# about djnago , template does not exits

Tags: django, error-handling

I'm getting the following error :

> OSError at /my_view
> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Django\Project\Project\core\template\index.html\index.html'
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    [http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_view\](http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_view%5C)
> Django Version: 4.2.3
> Exception Type: OSError
> Exception Value:    
> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Django\Project\Project\core\template\index.html\index.html'

I tried to render a template on web page,
and I expected it to render the page

Comment: Please post your relevant code from your views.py, your urls.py and template file.

Comment: actually i got a temporary solution i.e. replit , now  i am coding on replit

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the invalid argument: `C:\\Django\\Project\\Project\\core\template\\index.html\\index.html`.

Did you end up with `\\index.html\\index.html` (the file name twice) on accident? You'll need to provide more context for others to help better.